# Fatal error: The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I've installed PostgreSQL 14.1, and pgAdmin4 6.4. When I try to run pgAdmin 4 i get a fatal error "The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted". I've tried running it as administrator and deleting files at "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin, I'm sure that the PostgreSQL server is working since it's service at services.msc is running.

Here are logs from running pgAdmin4. I can see that something is wrong here, but I don't know how to fix this:

```
    pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\miloscvj\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\python.exe -s C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
  - APPDATA: C:\Users\miloscvj\AppData\Roaming
  - CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \\.\pipe\crashpad_6036_OOREQHHBCDZZAVHT
  - CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Whoa! NW.js has crashed. Relaunch now?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
  - CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
  - CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - COMPUTERNAME: MILOSCVJPC
  - ComSpec: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
  - DriverData: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
  - ESET_OPTIONS:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  - HOMEDRIVE: C:
  - HOMEPATH: \Users\miloscvj
  - JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-8.0.265.01-hotspot\
  - JD2_HOME: C:\Users\miloscvj\AppData\Local\JDownloader 2.0
  - LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\miloscvj\AppData\Local
  - LOGONSERVER: \\MILOSCVJPC
  - NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 4
  - OneDrive: C:\Users\miloscvj\OneDrive
  - OneDriveConsumer: C:\Users\miloscvj\OneDrive
  - OS: Windows_NT
  - Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Users\miloscvj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\miloscvj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Users\miloscvj\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\miloscvj\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
  - PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: 57d2b65d-0a0b-4650-b1c3-812570ba5026
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 1310
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
  - PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
  - PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
  - PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
  - PROCESSOR_REVISION: 170a
  - ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
  - ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
  - ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
  - ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
  - PSModulePath: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
  - PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
  - SystemDrive: C:
  - SystemRoot: C:\Windows
  - TEMP: C:\Users\miloscvj\AppData\Local\Temp
  - TMP: C:\Users\miloscvj\AppData\Local\Temp
  - USERDOMAIN: MILOSCVJPC
  - USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: MILOSCVJPC
  - USERNAME: miloscvj
  - USERPROFILE: C:\Users\miloscvj
  - VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
  - windir: C:\Windows
  - __COMPAT_LAYER: Installer
--------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 39, in <module>
    import config
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\config.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pgadmin.utils import env, IS_WIN, fs_short_path
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from socketio import socketio_manage  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\socketio\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\socketio\client.py", line 7, in <module>
    import engineio
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\engineio\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\engineio\client.py", line 12, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 118, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\requests\certs.py", line 15, in <module>
    from certifi import where
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 672, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 632, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 157, in load_module
    notify_module_loaded(module)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\wrapt\decorators.py", line 469, in _synchronized
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 135, in notify_module_loaded
    hook(module)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wrapt_certifi.py", line 27, in apply_patches
    generate_pem()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wincerts.py", line 121, in generate_pem

    for pem in get_pems():
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wincerts.py", line 41, in get_pems
    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
  File "ssl.py", line 770, in create_default_context
  File "ssl.py", line 591, in load_default_certs
  File "ssl.py", line 583, in _load_windows_store_certs
ssl.SSLError: [ASN1] nested asn1 error (_ssl.c:3992)
```

Comment: do you have a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

> delete sessions record at
> `C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\pgadmin4\User Data\Default\Sessions`
> Then restart pg4admin